# Combining 3 functions into one function

Tags: r, function, nested-function

I am trying to set up a function that checks the data then runs the appropriate function.

I have tried to move tbl1 and tbl2 into TBL.Fun. It won't run.

```
TBL.fun <- function (x,y){
  if(length(y)==1) tbl1(x[,y])
  else if(length(y)==2) tbl2(x[,y[1]],x[,y[2]])
  else print("Only two columns of data, kiddo!")

}

tbl1 <- function(x){
  tbl <- ftable(x)
  ptbl<- round(prop.table(tbl)*100,2)
  out <- tbl
  out[] <- paste(tbl,"(",ptbl,"%)")
  return(out)
}

tbl2 <- function(x,y){
  tbl <- ftable(x,y)
  ptbl<- round(prop.table(tbl)*100,2)
  out <- tbl
  out[] <- paste(tbl,"(",ptbl,"%)")
  return(out)
}
```

I want the TBL.fun to check the data and based on that check, compute and print the correct table. After I combined the functions into

```
TBL.fun1 <- function (x,y=NULL){
  if(is.vector(x)==T && is.null(y)==T) tbl1(x)
  else tbl2(x,y)
  tbl1 <- function(x){
    tbl <- ftable(x)
    ptbl<- round(prop.table(tbl)*100,2)
    out <- tbl
    out[] <- paste(tbl,"(",ptbl,"%)")
    return(out)
  }

  tbl2 <- function(x,y){
    tbl <- ftable(x,y)
    ptbl<- round(prop.table(tbl)*100,2)
    out <- tbl
    out[] <- paste(tbl,"(",ptbl,"%)")
    return(out)
  }
}
```

After combining the functions i ran a `dput()` on the function with a single variable.

```
Gender <- c("F","F","F","M","M","M")
Race <- c("Black","White","Asian","White","Black","Black")
> sam_dat <- cbind(Gender,Race)
dput(TBL.fun1(sam_dat[,1]))
function (x, y) 
{
    tbl <- ftable(x, y)
    ptbl <- round(prop.table(tbl) * 100, 2)
    out <- tbl
    out[] <- paste(tbl, "(", ptbl, "%)")
    return(out)
}
> TBL.fun1(sam_dat[,1])
```

Comment: could you give a `dput()` of your data?

Comment: what is a dput()?

Comment: if you use the function `dput()` on the variables you use to run `TBL.fun()` we can reproduce the error. `dput()` returns the structure of the variable, so others can paste it on their R console and have the same exact variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have to include all functions in `TBL.fun1`, you just call them, depending on the condition.

You can also simplify the condition as `is.vector` and `is.null` already return logical values, so you dont have to test for `== TRUE`.

I inserted 2 print statements, so you can see that both functions are called.

```
TBL.fun1 <- function (x, y = NULL){
  if (is.vector(x) && is.null(y)) {
    print("used tbl1")
    tbl1(x) 
  } else {
    print("used tbl2")
    tbl2(x, y)
  }
}

Gender <- c("F","F","F","M","M","M")
Race <- c("Black","White","Asian","White","Black","Black")
sam_dat <- cbind(Gender,Race)

a = TBL.fun1(sam_dat[,1])
b = TBL.fun1(sam_dat[,2], sam_dat[,1])
```

Comment: Thank you, the end goal is to construct a package of functions that I use all of the time and I thought all of the bits had to be in one function.

Comment: As long as the functions are in the same file and loaded before you execute `TBL.fun1`, you don't have to do anything, if they are in separate files, you would have to `source` them in you're environment. But if you build a package, the functions just have to be in the package and will be accessible everywhere (as long as you export them, otherwise they're just accessible from inside you're package).